# Possible to run a delayed code execution?

Tags: python, maya

Will it is possible to run a small set of code automatically after a script was run?

I am asking this because for some reasons, if I added this set of code into the main script, though it works, it will displays a list of tab errors (its already there, but it is stating that it cannot find it some sort).

I realized that after running my script, Maya seems to 'load' its own setup of refreshing, along with some plugins done by my company. As such, if I am running the small set of code after my main script execution and the Maya/ plugins 'refresher', it works with no problem. I had like to make the process as automated as possible, all within a script if that is possible...

Thus is it possible to do so? Like a delayed sort of coding method?
FYI, the main script execution time depends on the number of elements in the scene. The more there are, it will takes longer...

Comment: Could you create a subprocess of the refresher script and busy-wait until it is completed?

Comment: Include both scripts in a batch or shell ?

Comment: Just write a Maya Plugin, that starts your code after refreshing?

Comment: @SukritKalra What do you mean?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Like-wise, how should I go on about doing so? Pardon me for lack of knowledge..

Comment: @Dschoni I would try to refrain from creating a new plugin (I have got no idea too :() as it is only solely for one function - which is the script I done. No point in cluttering the 'space'

Comment: This sounds like the real problem is in the original scripts you're trying to run - the deferred execution is just an method of trying to get around a problem in the originals. If you'd post some more information -- like the errors and relevant parts of the scripts themselves -- you're much more likely to get actionable help

Answer (score 2):

Maya has a command [Maya.cmds.evalDeferred](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/evalDeferred.html) that is meant for this purpose. It waits till no more Maya processing is pending and then evaluates itself.

You can also use [Maya.cmds.scriptJob](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/scriptJob.html) for the same purpose.

**Note:** While eval is considered dangerous and insecure in Maya context its really normal. Mainly because everything in Maya is inherently insecure as nearly all GUI items are just eval commands that the user may modify. So the second you let anybody use your Maya shell your security is breached.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the problems. I do agreed that I have been asking pretty ridiculous (somewhat impossible) questions from time to time, partly because there are cases in which as you have stated, Maya is against me rather than the other way round. And honestly speaking, till date I am still pretty much lacking in how to script properly, the same goes for the different types of modules / plugins installed that Maya has.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. IT sounds to me like your tying stuff t maya GUI with a one layer approach while maya expects you to use a 2 layer one. YOu should have a self contained computation layer and then let the gui work its magic independently from this. This is how all of maya works trying to do it differently is a exercise of futility since maya might live without a GUI. Anyway you should probably ask a question of your design not so much on each step. As of now your digging yourself a grave each step you take takes you further form a solution that would actually work.

Comment: Also note it sounds to me that all your work could be circumvented with a getAttr